# How to make a proxy in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to make a proxy in node js. My requirement is :

When user go to url 'mydata.mywebsite.com' from browser, it should fetch the data from 'localhost:3000' and show it on the page.

I do not want redirection, means user and the browser should see the response is coming from 'mydata.mywebsite.com' and so the url should remains as 'mydata.mywebsite.com'.

EDIT :
All the links on google is helpful for making proxies over for localhost domains.
I want to make proxy server for some custom domain that is not localhost, (however running as a fake server on local machine).

In simple words i want to make a fake server with domain 'mydata.mywebsite.com', which is actually serving all request from a localhost server running on 3000 port. All to be done on client side machine. is it possible in nodejs.??

Comment: Stack overflow guidelines require you to try something, anything, and post a code snippet. Tutorials on this abound on the web. Try something then post what you have and what is causing you trouble.

Comment: Why do you want it in nodejs? May be you should try to use nginx or any other existing web-server?

Comment: Google first hit: http://www.catonmat.net/http-proxy-in-nodejs/ that pretty much does what you need.  Is there something more specific that is not working for you we can help you with?

Comment: i have already used the google first hit. but that is not following up with my requirement. It only listens on a particular port of localhost. Not on the some domain eg 'mydata.mywebsite.com'

Comment: @Koka, it's impossible to listen to particular domain. Sockets are binded to interface (or interfaces) and port number. You have to check hostname and accept or reject request in your software.

Comment: In simple words i want to make a fake server with domain 'mydata.mywebsite.com', which is actually serving all request from a localhost server running on 3000 port. All to be done on client side machine. is it impossible in nodejs.??

Comment: Please go through the edit of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

everything you need is in the core [http module](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html). Take a look at [request module](https://github.com/mikeal/request) as well

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  if (req.headers.host == 'mydata.mywebsite.com') {
    req.pipe(http.request({
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 3000,
      path: req.url,
      method: req.method
    })).pipe(res);
  }
}).listen(80);
```

Here `http.request` starts downstream request. `req.pipe` sends data to it, and `.pipe(res)` consumes response back. This is possible because both http request and response objects are node [streams](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html).

Comment: what if i change mydata.mywebsite.com to goolge.com?? It is opening the google page..! Why? I want to open localhost server response page.

Comment: waiting for your comment.

Comment: if you want to open localhost when you type google.com add `localhost google.com` line to your '/etc/hosts' file, but I guess it's not what you want and your question is incorrect

Comment: then what is the purpose of the above code in your answer?

Comment: PS : even when i enter ('mydata.mywebsite.com' then also nothing happens. I find the callback inside createServer is not called. When this callback is called?

Comment: it is called when http request is sent to port and ip address specified by `listen()` method. In my example it's port 80 and default interface of your local machine.

Comment: please let me know the purpose of your code.

Comment: of course when i got localhost, i get the host == 'localhost'.. then what is the meaning/purpose of checking if (req.headers.host == 'mydata.mywebsite.com'). host is always be 'localhost:80'.. and the if block will never be called. So what the code actually does??

Comment: no it's not. It's value of host header, you can set it whatever you want

Comment: Yeah, you are talking about apps like postman, junit etc.. ok.. possible.. And inside if block, the above code simply get the response from 3000 port on and put the response at 80 port. am i right? if so, the above is not my requirement, as i my request url will be "localhost". Rather my request url should be 'google.com' or 'mydata.mywebsite.com' etc..

Comment: no, if your server hostname is 'mywebsite.com' then 'mydata.mywebsite.com' typed in the browser will get you response proxied from localhost:3000. This could be server with public IP address and domain name you own with A record resolving to that IP address or simply local machine with local dns record ( e.i /etc/hosts file ) pointing mywebsite.com to 127.0.0.1

Comment: do i need to restart the system after updating /etc/hosts file??

Comment: usually not ( at least osx/linux )

Comment: can u please let me know the entry to be appended or prepended in etc/hosts. i am prepending 'localhost   mydata.mywebsite.com' and it does not do anything in my osx

Comment: add line '127.0.0.1 mywebsite.com' - http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-edit-the-mac-os-x-hosts-file-and-why-you-might-want-to/

Comment: this also did not have any effect..